# How to get the first value in a recursive function?

Tags: recursion

I'm trying to do a school quiz again.  I'm trying to match if my result is equal to number "x".  I wrote a recursive function, I always get the value 0, not the one I used to call the function (such as 153).  What should I change ?

```
public static boolean isArmstrong(int x, Armstrong s) {     
    while (a != true) {
        while (x != 0) {
                int number = x / 10;
                int remain = x % 10;
                s.push(remain);
                return isArmstrong(number, s);
            } 
                a = true;
        }

        if (getResult() == x) {
            System.out.println("True , result is : " + getResult());
        } else {
            System.out.println("False , x is : " + x + " result is : " + getResult());
//x always prints out 0 which ends the while loop.But i need to get the x value when i call the function

        }

        return true;

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've supplied incomplete information, no definition for the method `getResult()` nor for the type `Armstrong s`, but there are still some issues we can address.  First, your boolean method `isArmstrong()` never returns `false`, only `true`, so we can't expect it to detect non Armstrong numbers.  Second, you're doing too much in your recursive method, both the test for an Armstrong number and the announcing of the result -- these might best be handled by separate methods.

Below's a rework that changes `isArmstrong()` from a boolean method to one that returns its calculation as an integer. An input value of zero breaks the recursion causing a result to be returned.  We use a separate function to compare the argument to `isArmstrong()` against the returned value to announce success or failure:

```
public class Armstrong
{
    public static int isArmstrong(int x, int power) {
        if (x != 0) {
            int quotient = x / 10;
            int remainder = x % 10;

            return (int)Math.pow(remainder, power) + isArmstrong(quotient, power);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int number = 0, power = 0;

        if (args.length > 0) {
            try {
                power = args[0].length();
                number = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println("Argument " + args[0] + " must be an integer.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }

        int result = isArmstrong(number, power);

        if (result == number) {
            System.out.println("True, result is: " + result);
        } else {
            System.out.println("False, number is: " + number + " but result is: " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> java Armstrong 153
True, result is: 153
> java Armstrong 123
False, number is: 123 but result is: 36
> java Armstrong 1634
True, result is: 1634
> java Armstrong 1635
False, number is: 1635 but result is: 2003
>
```